# Run-time error '91': Object Variable or with Block variable not set (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing issue while running a set of vba code **Error: Run-time error '91': Object Variable or with Block variable not set (VBA)**.

**VBA Code:**

```
    NEWROW2 = SHT1.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NEWROW3 = SHT1.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Row1 = "G" & NEWROW3
    Row2 = "G" & NEWROW2
    Row3 = Row1 & ":" & Row2
    
    SHT1.Range("A1").Value = Row2
    
    SHT1.Range(Row3).Value = TherapyNameRe
```

**Variables Defined:**

```
Dim NEWROW2, NEWROW3, NEWROW4, NEWROW5, NEWROW6 As Integer
Dim Total_data, Row1, Row2, Row3 As Range
```

Please refer below image for your reference

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help:)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)

Comment: You have declared `Row3` As `RANGE` and you are trying to store a string in it. Since you are using it as a `STRING` in `SHT1.Range(Row3).Value`, do not declare it as `RANGE`. Declare it as `STRING`. For example `Dim Row3 As String`

Comment: Don't forget to declare all your variables in the same way, i.e. `Dim Total_data As Range, Row1 As Range, Row2 As Range, Row3 As Range` if you do want them all to be defined as a Range object, the way you have it now Total_Data, Row1 and Row2 are of the Variant type (default type when nothing is specified)

Comment: Welcome to SO. @FunThomas gave you the solution already but I want you to know that when you do `Dim NEWROW2, NEWROW3, NEWROW4, NEWROW5, NEWROW6 As Integer` only last variable is being declared as `Integer`. Rest of them are unespcified so VBA will create them as `Variant`. Next time do `Dim NEWROW2 As Integer, NEWROW3 As Integer, NEWROW4 As Integer, NEWROW5 As Integer, NEWROW6 As Integer`

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your help, it worked :)